# Delphi DPR/Library path confusion (interference between D10 and D11)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, delphi-11-alexandria

I have Delphi 10.4 and Delphi 11.2. I find Delphi 11 too buggy to be used and I stick with my Delphi 10 (for the moment).

But Delphi 10 has also some bugs in its VCL, that were fixed in D11. So, I took Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas from D11 and copied into a separate folder (VCL_FIX). Then in Delphi 10, I include that file into my projects:

```
program MyProgram;

uses
  FastMM4,
  Forms,
  ...
  Vcl.ExtCtrls in 'C:\Packages\**VCL_FIX**\Alexandria_VCLs\Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas';
```

The problem is that now, having D11 installed in parallel with D10, when I *Ctrl+click* the "Vcl.ExtCtrls" in the DPR file, it opens the real file from D11 ( c:\Delphi\Alexandria\source\vcl\ ), not the one from my "VCL_FIX" folder.

Why?

1. I don't understand how D10 gets access to D11 files... I thought they are individual installations.
2. And why the real D11 file takes precedence? The DPR clearly says that the file should be taken from VCL_FIX folder.

Comment: Seems to me this is caused by the Windows `path` environment variable. Try to remove all Delphi entries from it and test.

Comment: Do you have installed all updates to Delphi 11? We are currently at D11.2.

Comment: That’s not really recommanded to switch source files, you can have side effect. Would be better to ask here or open issue at embarcadero quality center

Comment: @fpiette - Yes. My Delphi 11 is up to date. 11.2 + patches. But the IDE and the compiler are quite unstable.

Comment: *The DPR clearly says*: The DPR is only used when compiling or building. The IDE looks in the search paths and library paths in Project->Options as well as the project directory, which is probably where your copy of the file should be instead of in Packages.

Comment: Your scheme won't necessarily work. I think that, if there are definition changes to any properties or methods then any unit before the inclusion of **FIX** will reference the D10 unit and not see them.  And anything after that will reference the  D11 unit.  This is for the compiler.  The linker should be fine.  Anything on the form will reference the D10 unit for properties while editing. And as Ken has mentioned, the path for ctrl-click is definitely from the Project/Options and Project Directory.

Comment: @RohitGupta - You cannot have any definition changes (properties, methods, etc) when you recompile the file this way. You can change the code after "implementation" but you cannot change the definitions of the methods.

Comment: @fpiette - I tried D11 with GExperts installed. GExperts is highly experimental. Maybe it was the one crashing the IDE.